# Calling yii from c

Tags: php, c, yii

I'm trying to activate a *PHP* script from a *C* file but I get an error when the script tries to activate a `CActiveRecord` class. I guess it's a problem related to yii.
Anyway, here is what I got:
`Fatal error: Class 'CActiveRecord' not found in /var/www/.../models/SomeModelTbl.php on line 16`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you post the code you are working on?

Comment: [Yii has a special way to run command line scripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console), are you using that?

Comment: @DCoder I don't think you understood my problem, I'm trying to call `php` from `c` and from what I'm seeing that link is for running command lines from yii. 
  

@Letmesee, If you mean how do I call the php script than this is the command written in the `c` file: execl("/usr/bin/php","/usr/bin/php","/var/www/project/protected/modules/some_module/components/someFile.php","someParameter",NULL);

Comment: To run Yii code outside a webserver, you're supposed to implement your code as a CConsoleCommand and call `yiic yourCommandName`, not call your script directly. That's what the link I gave you is about.

Comment: @DCoder, oh my bad. Didn't undrstood you at first, I'll look into it, Thanks!